# Can I build an EBow myself?

Tags: guitar, guitar-effects, construction, archeterie

It's possible to get some crazy sounds using an EBow on the guitar. I know that it works by creating an electromagnetic field to move the strings. Has anybody tried to build one? Are any schematics available?

Comment: The ebow doesn't just use an electromagnet, it also senses the pitch of the string using a small pickup, and amplifies the pitch using the electromagnet causing the sustain. If it didn't use a pickup, the pitch it would have to use an arbitrary frequency, which would cause the string's vibrations to cancel or switch to odd harmonics.

Comment: You might also get answers at [the Electronics SE site](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [this page.](http://www.diyguitarist.com/DIYStompboxes/EbowTech.htm) It provides some decent background technical information.

[image]

[Source](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_z9GAP98bLtw/SyKTvmBtlFI/AAAAAAAAGaQ/0RH86WeYVp4/s1600-h/ebow_amp.png)

It sounds like a fairly interesting DIY project, considering as real ones go for over £70-80!

Hope this helps.

Comment: of course calling the contraption an e-bow (and especially trying to sell it) would cause you serious legal trouble. 
It's a trademarked name, and there might be patents involved as well.